# Not able to Extract query string on the ServerSide in NextJS

Tags: next.js, backend, query-string, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I'm using NextJS app directory structure for routing.

/app/page.jsx

```
import ListProduct from "@components/products/ListProduct";
import axios from "axios";
const getProducts = async (min, max, category, rating) => {
  console.log(min,max,category,rating) 
  const {data} = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.AXIOS_URL}/api/products?min=${min}&max=${max}&category=${category}&rating=${rating}`
  );
  return data;
};

const Home = async ({searchParams}) => {
  const min = searchParams.min || "";
  const max = searchParams.max || "";
  const category = searchParams.category || "";
  const rating = searchParams.rating || "";

  const products = await getProducts(min, max, category, rating);

  //Filtering of data.

  return <ListProduct data={products} />;
};

export default Home;
```

- in above code I have fetched the query string on client side using SearchParams and passed to function in parameter which is being used to pass as URL in axios.
- till now data is being properly showed but it won't passed in server side.
- here is the /app/api/products/route.js

```
import Product from "@backend/models/product";
import {connectToDB} from "@backend/utils/connectToDB";

export const POST = async (request) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();
    const data = await request.json();

    const newProduct = new Product(data);

    await newProduct.save();
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(newProduct), {status: 201});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return new Response(error, {status: 500});
  }
};

export const GET = **async (req, res)** => {
  try {
    **console.log(req.query);** 
    await connectToDB();
    const data = await Product.find({});
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({
        data: data,
        message: "Products fetched successfully",
      }),
      {status: 201}
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response("Failed to fetch a Product", {status: 500});
  }
};
```

- here i have consoled req.query but it's showing me undefined.
- I can't use useRouter(), searchParams or anything on server side , I just want to get the query params using request if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `req.query` does not exist in newer versions of `app` directory. try this:

```
export async function GET(req: Request) {

   const url = new URL(req.url)
   const rating=url.searchParams.get('rating')
}
```